# Arduino signed int can't fire timer > 15 seconds

Tags: timers, arduino-pro-mini, oscillator-clock

I have tried to use different libraries like `TimeAlarms` , `SimpleTimer`, `Timer` and others. My goal is to call function periodically every minute or so. Each library works fine when repeat time is less than 15 seconds ( maybe greater) but 30seconds,45seconds, 60seconds doesn't work at all.

It seems something with internal timer.

I also use NRF24l01 Mesh library.

Please help to solve the problem

**SOLVED**

The issue was that I used int type instead of long. but I don't understand why 60 000 cannot be stored in int type which is 4 bytes (2^32)

Comment: Please post code, links to libraries, and any projects that you might have copied code from. Even better is to isolate the issue to a test sketch that others can run and understand the issue. If this is an issue with any of the libraries it will have to be solved there.

Comment: Thank you for the help. but the issue was that I used int type instead of long. but I don't understand why 60 000 cannot be stored in int type which is 4 bytes (2^32)

Comment: A code snippet had shown that. The take-away is that you should provide more info. BW: int is only 2 bytes on Arduino/AVR. Remember this is an 8-bit MCU.

Comment: And here is a link for more info on the AVR ABI https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc.

Comment: An `int` on Arduino is only 16-bits (2 byte). It's also `signed`. So the maximum value is `2^15-1`.

Comment: Please post an answer explaining this, I will accept it

Comment: Since you found out the solution yourself, you should add the answer yourself.

Comment: You could summarize what people told you, and then post your complete solution. You are allowed to answer your own questions. The maximum in an `int` on the Arduino is 32767 so I am a bit surprised 30 seconds didn't work.